# API Scan is not scanning the apis from swagger-ui.html in OWASP ZAP

Tags: api, authentication, swagger, owasp, zap

I tried below commands

```
docker pull owasp/zap2docker-weekly

docker run -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t https://dummyexample.com/swagger-ui.html -f openapi -g gen.conf -r testreport.html -z "-config replacer.full_list(0).description=auth1 \
        -config replacer.full_list(0).enabled=true \
        -config replacer.full_list(0).matchtype=REQ_HEADER \
        -config replacer.full_list(0).matchstr=Authorization \
        -config replacer.full_list(0).regex=false \
        -config replacer.full_list(0).replacement='Bearer eyJraWQiOiIyABCDEFG'"
```

I am getting output as

WARN-NEW: Unexpected Content-Type was returned [100001] x 2

https://dummyexample.com/swagger-ui.html (200 OK)

https://dummyexample.com/swagger-ui.html/ (200 OK)

WARN-NEW: Incomplete or No Cache-control Header Set [10015] x 1

https://dummyexample.com/swagger-ui.html (200 OK)

WARN-NEW: Content Security Policy (CSP) Header Not Set [10038] x 1

https://dummyexample.com/swagger-ui.html (200 OK)

FAIL-NEW: 0 FAIL-INPROG: 0  WARN-NEW: 3 WARN-INPROG: 0  INFO: 0 IGNORE: 0   PASS: 113

The problem is I am not able to scan all the api's from swagger as I require authentication for it.
But I have provided the correct Bearer Token, then also all the api's are not captured and scanned.
I need to do this only through owasp/zap2docker-weekly image. I don't want to use ZAP UI.
I tried disabling the api.disablekey=true but same output.

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk/:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t https://dummyexample.com/swagger-ui.html -f openapi -g gen.conf -r testreport.html -z "-config api.disablekey=true"
```

Please help me with this. I am missing something.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why are you passing the swagger UI? You need to pass the actual API def'n

Answer (score 0):

While the replacer should work fine I'd recommend using the authentication env vars: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/start/features/authentication/#envvars